# Custom membership provider and Unity injection

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, custom-membershipprovider

I have created a custom membership provider for my MVC4 solution. The problem is I can't get it injected through Unity.

I have tried using constructor injection, but then I get the parameterless constructor error. If I try using InjectionProperty its does not change any of my properties. I have tried use the DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(); it returns null.

I have first attached the provider through the web.config:

```
  <membership defaultProvider="ExtendedServiceMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ExtendedServiceMembershipProvider" type="Foo.Providers.Security.BoxMembershipProvider, Foo" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="ExtendedServiceRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ExtendedServiceRoleProvider" type="Foo.Providers.Security.BoxRoleProvider, Foo" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Is this the right approach?
Hope some of you have a solution to my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is create an empty membership provider that does nothing more than call into the MVC Dependency Resolver to fetch the real `Membership Provider`. By doing this you achieve three things:

- This implementation has a default constructor and can be configured in the web.config.
- The implementation is a MVC infrastructure component and is decoupled from the actual membership provider that contains the implementation (that you probably want to test).
- This infrastructure component has no dependency on Unity (or any other container), but just on MVC3 which lowers the coupling of the container itself.

The implementation might look like this:

```
public class DependencyResolverMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private static MembershipProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            var provider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MembershipProvider>();

            if (provider == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Make sure the MembershipProvider is registered.");
            }

            return provider;
        }
    }

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get { return Provider.ApplicationName; }
        set { Provider.ApplicationName = value; }
    }

    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, 
        string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        return Provider.ChangePassword(username, oldPassword, newPassword);
    }

    public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, 
        string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        return Provider.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(username,
            password, newPasswordQuestion, newPasswordAnswer);
    }

    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, 
        string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, 
        string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, 
        out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        return Provider.CreateUser(username, password, email,
            passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, providerUserKey,
            out status);
    }

    // Implement all other methods here
}
```

This is still a lot of work, since the `MembershipProvider` has a lot of methods. There are two ways you can make this easier:

- Use a framework such as [Griffin.MvcContrib](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib), which already do such a thing for you and do it even in a more pleasant way, since it separates the responsibilities that are inside these classes and expose a few new interfaces that you can implement for this functionality.
- Prevent any part of the system of depending on the static `Membership` class, but always inject a `MembershipProvider` into those classes or even better: don't use the `MembershipProvider` but simply inject the interfaces that are probably behind that `MembershipProvider` (such as `IUserRepository` and `IPasswordManager`).

Comment: Thanks that's make more sense to me. Finally I decided to use custom login with an already created MembershipService.